# How to inegrate CAS authentication with Apache wicket application?

Tags: java, wicket, cas

I am working on a project where I have to integrate CAS authentication into an Apache Wicket application. Though I am still a beginner in web-development, I know how to implement CAS authentication into simple web-app (using Spring-security), where I define a directory/files which need authentication before User can access them. Following is the example CAS application structure, I have created and tested. In the below example, access to files in "secure" directory need authentication.

[image: My existing CAS appication]

The contents of applicationContext-security.xml are as below.

```
    <security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED"></security:intercept-url>
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter"></security:custom-filter>
</security:http>
```

But if I have to secure files in apache wicket application, how can I do this? I would like to start my application by displaying "edu.vt.geoserver.HomePage.html" without authentication and to set authentication requirement to access files in "edu.vt.geoserver.securePages". Please see the attached structure of my target application.

[image: Target wicket application where I would like CAS authentication]

Let me know if anyone can help me in this regard. I have seen the Jasig's unofficial cas-client for wicket application, but still not sure what all changes I will need to do. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if everything else is set up correctly, you probably just have to mount your secure pages to the correct URLs in the init method of your Application class like this:

```
mountPage("/secure/GeoServerFrontPage", edu.vt.geoserver.securePages.GeoServerFrontPage.class);
```

Since your Spring Security is configured to secure all pages in the URL pattern "/secure/**", calling your GeoServerFrontPage should then trigger a login.

You can also have a look at the method mountPackage() to mount all pages in your securePages-Package with one line of code... .

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thank you Tom, I will try and let you know if I succeed in getting the web-app running.

Comment: Did you get it to work? For a working example of Spring Security with Wicket you can have a look at https://github.com/thombergs/wicket-spring-security-example.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I got it working. It was easy fix. I appreciate your help.